# Query records that does not have an entry in another table using Sequelize include clause

Tags: mysql, orm, sequelize.js

Given Users table and Ratings table

How do I query all user records from Users table that does not have any rating record in Ratings table **using Sequelize include clause**

Note: Sequelize version 5.x

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways depending on how your models are defined.

**1.** Get all `Users` along with `Ratings` by using [Sequelize Eager Loading](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-usage.html#eager-loading). Then filter where user does not have any ratings.

```
const users = Users.findAll({
  include: [Ratings]
});
const filteredUsers = users.filter(user => user.ratings.length === 0);
```

**2.** Get all `userIds` from the `Ratings` table and then pass these `userIds` to the where clause using the `notIn` [Sequelize operator](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#operators)

```
const ratings = Ratings.findAll({
  attributes: ["userId"],
  group: ["userId"]
});
const userIds = ratings.map(rating => rating.userId);
const filteredUsers = Users.findAll({
  where: {
    userId: { [Op.notIn]: userIds }
  }
});
```

Comment: that is exactly why i dislike sequelize

Comment: It would be a lot better to have a single database query that does everything rather than hitting the database twice

Answer (score 1):

Try incorporating a sequelize literal in the where clause:

```
const ratings = Ratings.findAll({
                attributes: ["userId"],
                group: ["userId"],
                where: {
                         $and: [ 
                                sequelize.literal(`NOT EXISTS (
                                        SELECT 1 FROM Ratings r
                                        WHERE r.userId = User.id
                                        )`),
                                ],
                        },
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a relationship between `Users` and `Ratings` in your models, this can be accomplished in a single query by using a left outer join followed by a filter on the client side.

In your model definition:

```
Users.hasMany(Ratings, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Ratings.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
```

In your query:

```
const users = await Users.findAll({
    include: [
        { 
            model: Ratings,
            required: false // left outer join
        }
    ]
});

const usersWithoutRatings = users.filter(u => u.user_ratings.length === 0);
```

Comment: FYI: The first method in the answer uses a single query